# pass python variable to shell script

Tags: python, shell

I have a shell script (myshell.sh) and inside this shell I run a python script (mypython.py). How can I pass a python variable to the shell script? I simply printed my variable at the end of my python script and used the following command in the shell script to run the python script:

```
a=$(python mypython.py arg1 arg2 arg3)
```

However, $a has a lot of garbage info along with my variable. How can I have only my python variable in shell script after I run my python script?
My python script looks like:

```
print("hi")
print("bye")
a="goodbye"
print(a)
```

and I want to get variable a inside shell script.

Comment: can you show your python script as well, or a [mcve] that reproduces the issue?

Comment: `$a` will contain everything that the Python script prints. if you only want it to have that one variable, don't print anything else.

Comment: In python script, I use API to get xml file and ... . So, xml info will come into $a and I do not want those info.

Comment: So *don't print the XML file*. There should be no reason to.

Comment: Problem is solved. Thanks guys!